# Page using jQuery displays bad in Firefox (IE and Chrome ok)

Tags: jquery

i am learning jQuery from tusplus website and i want to have a FAQ section with questions and when user point to the question, the right answer slided down.

I've implemented it but it works good only in IE and Chrome, but bad in Mozilla. Anyone know why? Thanks.

Live demo: www.lukashamrla.cz/pokus.html

Code:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("dd").addClass("hide");

            $("dt").on("mouseenter", function(){
                $(this).next().slideDown().siblings('dd').slideUp();
            })
        });
```

Comment: jQuery is a library, it doesn't "displays"

Comment: You have to post relevant code in question

Comment: It's in the live demo. But ok, i've added to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's the `.siblings('dd')` that may be mis-behaving, tweak this to `slideUp()` only of those that are hidden via [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to prevent `.slideUp()` actioning `dd` elements regardless of it's status:

```
$("dd").addClass("hide");
$("dt").on("mouseenter", function () {
    $(this).next().slideDown().siblings('dd:visible').slideUp();
});
```

#### **Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lsy9v/**